# Numpy array indexing issue : shape mismatch of indexing arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to select specific elements of an array but instead of slices I want to use an array of indexes for the second dimension i.e. instead of `data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],0:4]` I want something like that `data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],np.array([0,1,2,3])]`. However the code below throws an error : `IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (4,)`.

```
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data2d = np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,(10,4))
    dir1 = np.array([2,1,3])
    dir2 = np.array([2,3,3])
    dir3 = np.array([1,1,3])
    dir4 = np.array([0,1,2,3])
    print(data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],0:4].shape) # works fine
    print(data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],dir4].shape) # does not work
    pass
```

I understand the issue of the dimension mismatch however how could I access the same elements of `data2d` with an indexing array instead of slices? It must be simple, but I could not find an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your array shapes:

```
data2d # (10,4)
dir1  # (3,)
dir2  # (3,)
dir3  # (3,)
dir4  # (4,)
```

this indexing:

```
data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],0:4]
np.array([dir1,dir2,dir2])  # (3,3)
# index first dim with a (3,3)
```

expect (3,3,4)

```
data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],dir4]
```

tries to use a (3,3) with (4,) - broadcast error; (3,3,1) and (4,) should work

```
arr = np.array([dir1,dir2,dir3])[:,:,None]
data2d[arr, dir4]
```

Answer (score 0):

`I understand the issue of the dimension mismatch however how could I access the same elements of data2d with an indexing array instead of slices? It must be simple, but I could not find an example.`

numpy arrays implement the `__getitem__` method which accepts `indices` or `slice` objects. the python `slice` object handles shape mismatch by itself. for example, if you use:

> print(data2d[[dir1,dir2,dir3],0:10].shape)

it will work fine too. but if you want to use numpy array as indices, you should handle shape mismatch or convert it to a `slice` object. maybe `np.s_` [index expression](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) can be useful for converting.